# Conditions on the function of a random variable is still a random variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

I am new to the theory of probability and feel stuck at some point.

The problem is as follows:
Let $X$ be a random variable and let $g:\mathbf{R}\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ be continuous and **strictly increasing**. Show that $Y=g(X)$ is a random variable.

And the solution is: If $y$ is in the range of $g(X)$, then $P(Y \leq y)=P(X \leq g^{-1}(y))\in \mathcal{F}$. Thus $Y$ is a random variable.

My understanding of the solution is that the continuous and strictly increasing conditions are required for the existence of the inverse function $g^{-1}(\cdot)$. But I think in the other way. Since the random variable $X$ is itself a function $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$, and then $Y$ is indeed a composition function $Y=g \circ X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$, isn't this suffices to show that $Y$ is a random variable? Then why do we need the strictly increasing condition? Is it because if the set $\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega) \leq g^{-1}(x)\}\notin \mathcal{F}$, then the composition function doesn't exist?

As a first-year Engineering student, I do not have an in-depth background in advanced mathematics, and maybe that causes the problem. Can anyone provide some more hints? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $g(X)$ is a random variable whenever $g$ is a Borel function (as the composition of measurable functions is measurable). So you're right; it suffices to assume that either $g$ is continuous or it's increasing.

Comment: @d.k.o. Beat me to it! Let me delete what I was writing... =D